# Numpy - How do you normalize specific features in a dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

There is set of data that has a mixture of continuous and symbolic data, such as the following:

```
data = [[duration, protocol, bytes, rate],
        [0,        tcp,      215,   0.45],
        [4,        udp,      1474,  0.63],
        [63,       icmp,     30,    0.07]]
```

The 1st, 3rd, and 4th columns are continuous features while the 2nd column is symbolic.

Is there a way to normalize the 1st, 3rd, and 4th columns without touching the 2nd, and without having to remove the second from the set of data?

**Edit:** For this problem, I want to normalize the data by making each column between 0 and 1 based on the min and max of each column.

Comment: The short & flippant answer to your question is yes.  The key is what do you mean by normalize.  The term "normalize data" has many different meanings.  What specifically do you want to do with the the data?

Comment: Updated Question, I am using the data to mess around with some AI stuff.  I will be  manipulating the data in different ways and wanted to see if there was a way to modify certain groups of data to make is easier to process while ignoring others.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to normalize a particular column in the way you want and then call it on the columns you want. For example:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array([['duration', 'protocol', 'bytes', 'rate'],
                [0,           'tcp',      215,     0.45],
                [4,           'udp',      1474,    0.63],
                [63,          'icmp',     30,      0.07]])

def normalize_column(col):
    values = [float(x) for x in data[1:, col]]
    minimum = np.min(values)
    maximum = np.max(values)
    r = maximum - minimum
    data[1:, col] = (values - minimum) / r
    
for col in (0, 2, 3):
    normalize_column(col)
    
data
```

```py
array([['duration', 'protocol', 'bytes', 'rate'],
       ['0.0', 'tcp', '0.128116', '0.678571'],
       ['0.063492', 'udp', '1.0', '1.0'],
       ['1.0', 'icmp', '0.0', '0.0']], dtype='<U8')
```